# how to find the max number of variables in stack

Tags: c, callstack

During the execution of the following program what is the maximum number of variables that are bound in a time in the stack:

```
int x, y, z;

int g(int a, int b) {
  int c = 5 * a + b;
  return c;
}

int f(int a, int b) {
  a = g(a, 5);
  return g(b, a);
}

int main() {
  int a, b, c;
  x = y = z = 0;
  a = 5; b = 6;
  c = f(a, b);
  printf("%d", c);
}
```

please if anyone knows how to find that. Can you explain me what to do in order to find it in every code that might be given.
 there are no any optimizations.

Another example:

```
int x,y;

int f(int a){
  if (a!=5)
    return f(--a);
  else 
    return a;
}

int main(){
  int a,b;
  a=8;b=6;
  x=f(a);
  y=f(b);
  printf("%d", x+y);

  return 0;
}
```

Is this above the answer 6? Because the first return, returns a variable 3 times.. and the second return returns one time a number and we have two variables in main so 6?

Comment: @Ilya I think editing code according to your convention is probably not the best thing to do, and does not follow SO rules....

Comment: @tomsoft, thank you for your feedback! I'll read again SO rules. (for me it was hard to read initial version of the question, so I decided to improve it. But may be it was wrong decision. Thank you!)

Answer (score 2):

You could run your program step by step in your head (or in a debugger) and could count all the active variables in every frame of the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (then get the maximal sum of them).

In your particular example, assuming no optimization, the deepest call stack happens at `return c;` statement in `g` called by `f`  called by `main`. So we have 3 call stack frames with 3 variables for `g` (`a`,`b`,`c`; I am assuming that formals are like local variables, this is not always true in practice!), 2 variables for `f` (`a`,`b`), and 3 variables for `main`.

Your teacher is probably expecting you to draw the call stack at it deepest state. I leave that to you.

In practice, several variables do not take any stack space, e.g. because they sit in a register, or share a stack slot with another variables. This is compiler and [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and processor-architecture and operating-system specific.

However, as [Ilya answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26401948/841108), a good compiler would transform your program for [optimization purposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) so in practice the answer could be different.

If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you may try to look at the generated assembler code (using `gcc -fverbose-asm -S`) and you'll see that the result and the number of used variables depends upon the optimization flags (i.e. `-O1`, `-O2`, etc... or lack of them). You could also use the GCC specific  [-fstack-usage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) flag. You might even try the `-fdump-tree-all` flag to `gcc` which gives hundred of dump files explaining in detail the various intermediate representations (Gimple, SSA, ...) of your program inside the compiler.

Read also wikipages on [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) (also perhaps [call/cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation)), [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and [inline expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion).

BTW, the presence of a call stack is not stricto sensu required by the [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard (but I know no implementation of C not using any call stacks). If you are curious, you should read A.Appel's old paper [*garbage collection can be faster than stack allocation*](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/45.ps) (which explains an implementation of [SML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) not using any call stack, because it is allocating every "call frame", a.k.a. "continuation frame", in a garbage collected heap).

I also suggest to compile your examples (with `gcc -Wall -g`) then run them *step by step* in the `gdb` debugger. Use often the `display`, `step`, `backtrace`, `frame` [commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) of `gdb`.

Comment: okay can you explain me what the answer will be for this case?

Comment: Then you should draw the *evolving* call stack on paper, or better with chalk on a board. I remember having taught exactly that -call stack for factorial 3, recursively implemented- at University (Paris 6, Master degree of computer science) last year. It took me 20 minutes.

Comment: Can you help me for the second one too? look ath the post again edited

Comment: No, I won't help. You need to read more things, draw on board or paper, experiment with GCC, step by step with the debugger, and understand more.

Comment: it has recursion on it..well actually we do that in the first year of cs..and isn't as easy because we did't even did examples in class..just these two are what they put in the tests

Comment: But you are also supposed to work on your own, reading and experimenting things. I gave some clues and references, but I won't do your homework or pass your exam! I agree that the concept of call stack is important and perhaps difficult to understand.

Comment: Lol it's not homework ..of course not they don't put as homework such easy things..it is for an exam I have..nad it onlt gets 6 marks from 100

Comment: so you will not explain me the other example?

Comment: Is the answer 6? because the first return ,returns a variable 3 times.. and the second return returns one time a number and we have two variables in main so 6?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on compiler and optimization settings. Good optimization algorithm will generate something like this:

```
int main() {
  printf("%d", 155);
}
```

Other algorithms will generate something else. So, try to use disassembler for compiled result.

Comment: @cbegi, so you can think that there are no any optimizations. They just check do you understand what is stack.

Comment: yes so can you help me ? explain me the stack what variables are saved there?

Comment: Have you read something about variables on stack? We need to know what do you understand to explain other things.

Comment: Try to explain in details, what exectly you don't understand (I think, it is better to extend your question).